# how to make an installable file?

Tags: installation

i have made a C language executable file... 
now i want to make it installable... 
i want to made my program installable which will install in specified drive location...
please... any one help me...
i will be thankful to you for this...

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the target platform but assuming its Windows you could create an MSI package to deploy your executable. An easy to use freeware program is [MAKEMSI](http://dennisbareis.com/makemsi.htm).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. You need to be more specific, what OS? Are you installing over a network, off a CD, etc? Does your executable need anything put into the registry, or require a specific path structure to run?

In Windows, using Visual Studio you can create an install project. I've also had good experiences with the [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tools available to make an installation package, on Windows I've been pleased with [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). I also recommend [HM NIS Edit](http://hmne.sourceforge.net/), an editor for creating NSIS scripts. It has some wizards so you can very quickly make something workable, and if you need to tweak something you can then worry about editing the script. It's a very powerful system.